# Why does my model produce too good to be true output?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, data-mining, overfitting

I am trying to run a binary classification problem on people with diabetes and non-diabetes.

For labeling my datasets, I followed a simple rule. If a person has `T2DM` in his medical records, we label him as positive cases (`diabetes`) and if he doesn't have T2DM, we label him as `Non-T2DM`.

Since there are a lot of data points for each subject, meaning he has a lot of lab measurements, a lot of drugs taken, a lot of diagnoses recorded, etc, I end up with 1370 features for each patient.

In my training, I have 2475 patients and in my testing, I have 2475 patients. (I already tried 70:30. Now am trying 50:50 still the same result (as 70:30))

My results are too good to be true as shown below

[image]

[image]

Should I reduce the number of features? Is it overfitting? Should I retain only the top features like top 20 features, top 10 features etc? can help me understand why is this happening?

**Detailed Update**

We check for the presence of T2DM by a set of diagnosis codes (like icd9,10 codes for T2DM and its complications etc). For ex: let's say if a patient has an icd9 code of 250 in his diagnosis records, we know that he was diagnosed with Type 2 diabetes. Let's not worry about the accuracy of this labeling approach at this point. Similarly, we label all other patients as `T2DM` and `Non-T2DM`.

But when we extract features, all his medical records are treated as features. The frequency of the drug/condition/lab tests will be used as a feature value. So, basically, the same diagnosis code (`250`) will be an input feature as well. Does it mean I should drop the diagnosis codes which were used to label a dataset from being used as features? But those are really very good features that can help me find out whether a patient is diagnosed with T2DM or not (when I apply my model on a totally different dataset). My objective is not to find out whether a patient will develop diabetes in the future or not but my objective is only to find out whether a patient is diabetic or not (from his records). So, I label my dataset with an imperfect heuristic as stated above and build a model. Once I build this model, I would like to validate this model at another site and find out how good is the model built using this imperfect heuristic in identifying whether a patient is diabetic or not. Hope this helps

Comment: Is there a T2DM feature that's derived from the medical record and used as input in the model? If you're deriving the target variable from the medical record, and then passing in the medical record as features, it makes sense that you'd perform this well - you're just looking for T2DM in medical record, exactly how you derived the target in the first place. Or if there's another highly correlated feature, like insulin use, it stands to reason that you could perform this well.

Comment: [Please don't just cross-post nearly-identical questions across multiple sites.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/493815/1352) Or at least link them together, so we don't duplicate work.

Comment: Metformin is a very common prescription drug for T2DM.  How much accuracy do you lose if you simply look for Metformin usage?

Comment: @NuclearHoagie - Please see the update to the question at the bottom. Hope this helps

Comment: @TheGreat The update make things clearer, thanks. But let me ask, why use machine learning in the first place? You already have a good rule-based method for determining if someone has T2DM from the medical record - that's how you're labeling people in the first place. It's unclear why you'd want to take the medical record, explicitly set up a rule for calling T2DM, and then go back to the medical record and ask, how can I call T2DM? You already did that in the first step.

Comment: Hi @NuclearHoagie. Let me know whether this makes sense. I use a rule to label my dataset. correct. But once I label I build a model to classify as T2DM and non-T2DM. Now this might seems redundant in my dataset. I feel this can be useful say if there is another hospital who wants to label their patients as T2DM or Non-T2DM. In this case, they don't have to just rely on rule-based approach but make use of my model (which will have lot more features) that can help them label their dataset in better way. Am I right to think this way?

Comment: of course, my model can work if they have similar datastructure and feature names etc. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: It sounds like you want to apply the model in cases where your rule cannot be applied, like in hospitals where they don't have the ICD9 codes, for example? In that case, you may want to remove the features involved in your rule, since you should expect to not have them in your application setting. If you do have the ICD9 codes, your rule is sufficient and you don't need ML. If you don't have ICD9 codes, an ML model that predicts using them isn't helpful either. Perhaps you should label the training data with the rule approach, and learn other features also associated with the rule.

Comment: Yes, I label the training data with the rule. Using that training data, I build a classification model (that learns a lot of other features to better identify T2DM and non-T2DM). I find out the list of important features. Now I know what are other factors that can help me find out whether a patient is T2DM or not. Am I not doing according to your last point which is `Perhaps you should label the training data with the rule approach, and learn other features also associated with the rule`

Comment: Yes, my point is that you may also want to remove the features used to define the T2DM training label, so that you *only* get those "other features" which were not used to define the label in the first place. If you don't, I'd expect most models will just choose the features you used initially to define T2DM, since *by definition*, that's all you need to identify T2DM. If you define T2DM from ICD9 codes, it'll be no surprise that you can take an ICD9 code and call T2DM.

Comment: I also asked a similar question here, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/109397/why-leaky-features-are-problematic?noredirect=1#comment111144_109397

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that these results are obtained on a valid test set with no data leakage, these results don't show overfitting because overfitting would cause great performance on the training set but significantly lower perfomance on the test set.

Make sure that your instances between the training and test set are truly distinct: there might be some data leakage, for example if there are duplicate records for the same patient.

Another potential flaw is the gold standard labeling: if the patient has this T2DM  in their medical record, it means that they are already diagnosed right? And since the features are also based on the medical record, it's likely that this medical record contains direct indications about this diagnosis (for example in the drugs prescribed to the patient). There are two interpretations about this:

- either the task is purposefully defined by this T2DM label, and in this case you can just enjoy the great performance but it's not technically about detecting diabetes in general.
- or the goal is to detect patients with diabetes including the ones who are not diagnosed yet, but then it's likely that your gold standard is incorrect for this task.

---

[edit following updated question]

Your update clarifies which exact task you're targeting, and it corresponds exactly to my first interpretation above: given that your goal is to predict which instances satisfy this T2DM criterion and that the features contain direct indications about it:

- I think you're right to keep these features, if a very useful information is available it would be absurd not to exploit it (assuming it's also available in the same form in any future dataset you plan to use, of course)
- The very high performance you obtain makes perfect sense for this task, it's not a bug. It simply happens that the task is easy, so the system is able to predict the label very well.

However this also means that you could do even better without any ML: currently the ML method gives you around 99% F-score because it doesn't perfectly represent the criterion used for the gold. But since the gold standard label is based entirely on the features, the most direct way to "predict" the label is to apply the criterion. There's no point using a complex ML method to predict an information that you can obtain from the same data more accurately with a deterministic method.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. Can you look at my update to the question at the bottom and see whether it can help you better

Comment: @TheGreat I edited my answer based on your update.

Answer (score 4):

Might be a case of Data leakage.

*For 1370 features, 2475 is a very small dataset for such an extreme result.*

*Please try* -

 Inspecting the misclassified records.

 Try removing the T2DM feature and note the dip

 Repeat the last step for all the features. *You must observe a negligible dip for other features and a very large dip for any feature which is causing the leakage.*

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. Can you look at my update to the question at the bottom and see whether it can help you better

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much looks like overfitting. It would be also interesting to know which algorythm did you use. Some are really sensitive to low number of instances / big number of features, and yYou have almost so many features as instances.

Trying checking first correlation between features and reduce the number of features with PCA or another method, before fitting your model again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the system can just learn your algorithm for labeling. If that is intended then you can just use that and throw away all the ML. If you want to predict, for example, the diagnosis of icd9=250, then of course there is no point to include icd9 as feature. Alternatively, if there is a history, you can use the record *just before the diagnosis of diabetes* as training example. You said you didn't want to predict whether a patient will be diabetic in the future. But you *do* want to predict whether someone is diabetic right now even if not diagnosed, right?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use a model like Decision Tree to see what actually is happening. Maybe there are couple of features in there that correlate in a big way to the label and the rest of the 1000+ features dont matter at all. It is possible (as someone else too point out) that one of the feature hiding in there (an icd with a certain response code) has a direct bearing the output label.